# Custom callbacks with warm up and cosine decay in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I referred to [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer) and especially the callback presented here. So, I decided to write out a callback inspired by [this one](https://github.com/facebookresearch/swav/blob/master/main_swav.py#L175). Basically, it combines warm-ups and cosine decays.

Here's how I coded it up -

```py
class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, base_lr=0.1, end_lr=0.001, warmup_steps=390*5):
        super(CustomSchedule, self).__init__()

        self.base_lr = base_lr
        self.end_lr = end_lr
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
    
    def __call__(self, step=390*35):
        warmup_lr_schedule = tf.linspace(0., self.base_lr, self.warmup_steps)
        iters = tf.range(step, dtype=tf.float32) 
        cosine_lr_schedule = tf.convert_to_tensor([self.end_lr + 0.5 * (self.base_lr - self.end_lr) * (1 + \
                        tf.math.cos(tf.constant(math.pi) * t / (step))) for t in iters])
        lr_schedule = tf.concat([warmup_lr_schedule, cosine_lr_schedule], axis=0)
        
        return lr_schedule
```

I verified if this is the one I wanted and indeed it is -

[image]

But when I pass this callback inside an optimizer I run into weird stuff -

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Here's [my Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/sayakpaul/0f75d0177cf6824f80fcc62cd49dc78f/scratchpad.ipynb) for full reproducibility. I am aware that the `LearningRateSchedule.__call__` method accepts a `step` argument and outputs the learning rate to use for that particular step. But the class I presented is outputting an entire schedule every step rather than the learning rate for that particular step. But I could not figure out how could achieve this effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Just semantics, but you're using a Scheduler, not a Callback. The `__call__` method of your scheduler will be called at each step to produce the new LR value, so you don't have to compute the entire schedule. The example that you linked illustrates this perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to this line:

```
tf.math.cos(tf.constant(math.pi) * t / (step))) for t in iters])
```

The problem is with iters. It is generated by tf.range, so it is a tensor, then you try to iterate over it.

```
tf.range(step, dtype=tf.float32)
for t in iters
```

Here is an implementation where you can control the decay_steps also. It can be passed into the optimizer directly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class WarmupOscillatingDecay(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, initial_learning_rate, decay_steps, warmup_steps, target_learning_rate):
        super(WarmupOscillatingDecay, self).__init__()
        self.initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate
        self.decay_steps = decay_steps
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
        self.target_learning_rate = target_learning_rate

    def __call__(self, step):
        # Warm-up phase
        warmup_lr = tf.cond(step < self.warmup_steps,
                            lambda: self.initial_learning_rate * step / self.warmup_steps,
                            lambda: self.initial_learning_rate)

        # Oscillating decay phase
        decay_lr = self.target_learning_rate + 0.5 * (self.initial_learning_rate - self.target_learning_rate) * (
            1 + tf.math.cos(np.pi * (step - self.warmup_steps) / self.decay_steps))

        # Combine warm-up and decay
        learning_rate = tf.cond(step < self.warmup_steps,
                                lambda: warmup_lr,
                                lambda: decay_lr)
        return learning_rate

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            "initial_learning_rate": self.initial_learning_rate,
            "decay_steps": self.decay_steps,
            "warmup_steps": self.warmup_steps,
            "target_learning_rate": self.target_learning_rate
        }

# Example usage
initial_lr = 0.1
decay_steps = 16000
warmup_steps = 390*5
target_lr = 0.001

lr_scheduler = WarmupOscillatingDecay(initial_lr, decay_steps, warmup_steps, target_lr)

# Plotting the learning rate schedule for visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

steps = np.arange(0, decay_steps + warmup_steps)
learning_rates = [lr_scheduler(step) for step in steps]

plt.plot(steps, learning_rates)
plt.xlabel('Step')
plt.ylabel('Learning Rate')
plt.title('Warmup Oscillating Decay Learning Rate Schedule')
plt.show()

# ...
lr_scheduler = WarmupOscillatingDecay(initial_lr, decay_steps, warmup_steps, target_lr)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_scheduler), loss=..., metrics=...)
```